# Include a new Dimension on CloudWatch Metrics

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

Today I am using five metrics to build a custom report (AsyncEventAge, PostRuntimeExtensionsDuration, Duration, Errors and Invocations).

My code to extract this info is similar to:

```
import * as AWS from 'aws-sdk';

  const cloudwatchParams: AWS.CloudWatch.GetMetricDataInput = {
    MetricDataQueries: [
      {
        Id: 'myMetricId',
        MetricStat: {
          Metric: {
            Dimensions: [
              {
                Name: 'FunctionName',
                Value: 'myFunctionName',
              },
              {
                Name: 'TriggerEvent', // new dimension that I want to create
                Value: 'ApiGateway', // event that triggered the lambda
              },
            ],
            MetricName: 'Invocations',
            Namespace: 'AWS/Lambda',
          },
          Period: 60 * 60 * 1,
          Stat: 'Sum',
        },
        ReturnData: true,
      },
    ],
    StartTime: '2023-10-05',
    EndTime: '2023-10-06',
  };

  const cloudwatch = new AWS.CloudWatch();
  const cloudwatchResponse = await cloudwatch.getMetricData(cloudwatchParams).promise();
```

What must I do in my lambda to enrich this metric with a new dimension? Is it possible to do it? if not, do I have any alternative to get a duration time of a lambda by the event caller? because I have lambdas called by two or more different events such as ApiGateway, Scheduler (warmer), or DynamoDBStream. I know that I can create a custom Metric Filter, but I want to get an accurate value in duration time, and I think I can reuse the Duration metric as the right way to do it.